# How to pipe a value into a popen3

Tags: ruby

I would like to pipe something into a command.
Something along the lines of `echo "test" | cmd somearg".

My first approach was to write to stdin like this:

```
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait|
  stdin.puts("test")
end
```

...but apparently that's not working.

So how do I pipe a value into command (and retain the possibility to read stdout/err)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait|
  stdin.puts("test")
  stdin.close
  # unless (err = stderr.read).empty? then raise err end
  stdout.read
end
```

Thing to note here is that you need to close (or, maybe flush) the `stdin` in order for `popen3` to feed it to the command. Then, you can read the `stdout` in a simple manner.

Also, make sure to keep in mind the following excerpt from the docs ([Open3#popen3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3)):

> You should be careful to avoid deadlocks. Since pipes are fixed length
>   buffers, ::popen3(“prog”) {|i, o, e, t| o.read } deadlocks if the
>   program generates too much output on stderr. You should read stdout
>   and stderr simultaneously (using threads or IO.select). However, if
>   you don’t need stderr output, you can use ::popen2. If merged stdout
>   and stderr output is not a problem, you can use ::popen2e. If you
>   really need stdout and stderr output as separate strings, you can
>   consider ::capture3.

Comment: Nope - unfortunately that's not working. I assume it's too late for stdin to be filled to have the same behaviour as `echo "test" | cmd`

Comment: Meh - an option was missing so missing so the cmd would accept the stdin. So - this is indeed working.